# Makefile - make can't find dependencies when linking

Tags: linker, makefile

Here is a simple makefile I made in order to compile a little program.

```
INCLUDE = include
OBJ = obj
SRC = src
BIN = bin
COMPILER = gcc -g -I $(INCLUDE)

VPATH = obj


main :  io.o alea.o tri.o main.o
        @echo "--------------LINKING----------------"
        ls obj
        $(COMPILER) $^ -o $(BIN)/$@

%.o : $(SRC)/%.c
        @echo "----" $@ "----"
        $(COMPILER) -c $< -o $(OBJ)/$@

clean:
        @echo "----Cleaning----"
        rm -v $(OBJ)/*
        rm -v $(BIN)/*
```

It seems to be all right but when I try to build my executable I get this output:

```
---- io.o ----
gcc -g -I include  -c src/io.c -o obj/io.o
---- alea.o ----
gcc -g -I include  -c src/alea.c -o obj/alea.o
---- tri.o ----
gcc -g -I include  -c src/tri.c -o obj/tri.o
---- main.o ----
gcc -g -I include  -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o
--------------LINKING----------------
ls obj
alea.o  io.o  main.o  tri.o
gcc -g -I include  io.o alea.o tri.o main.o -o bin/main
gcc: error: io.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: alea.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: tri.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: main.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main] Error 4
```

As you can see `make` doesn't find the right path to the files `.o` . I used `ls` to show that all the files in the folder obj are present and ready to be linked but unexpectedly `make` cannot find them when performing the main rule (even if I set `VPATH = obj`).

But when I try a second time (when the files are already compiled and just need to be linked) everything goes well:

```
--------------LINKING----------------
ls obj
alea.o  io.o  main.o  tri.o
gcc -g -I include  obj/io.o obj/alea.o obj/tri.o obj/main.o -o bin/main
```

Why `VPATH` is ignored when compiling for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are wrong. E.g in your rule for `main` you tell make that it depends off `.o` files in the local directory. The `.o` files in turn have a local rule that depends on files in `$(SRC)` but where the compile command produces files in `$(OBJ)`.

This can't work.

You can avoid such problems by producing the `.o` in the same subdirectory as the `.c` files. Typically you would have a separate makefile, there, such that you can go in that directory with a recursive call to make. Something like

```
objects : src
       $(MAKE) -C src
```

If you really want to produce your executable in a separate directory, again there should be a makefile in that directory and you would go recursively into that.

Comment: Yes but `VPATH` should do the work, no?
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html

Comment: No, I don't think that this is sufficient. It tells make where to search not where to produce. This is probably the reason that make then finds things on the second run.

Comment: Could you please explain it in a more detailed way? (I'm quite new to makefiles). If I'm not wrong you're saying that the makefile produces the .o files in the wrong place. How could this be possible if the output of gcc in the second rule is the correct directory? Furthermore before linking `ls` shows that the files are in the right place.
Does this happen because the evaluation of VPATH is done only once at the very beginning, when nothing as been compilated? This is the only explanation I can find so far.

Comment: As I understand it, `VPATH` is only scanned at the beginning to find files that otherwise aren't present, so typically source files. It is not looked up for intermediate files that could eventually be produced by rules. Your rule to produce `.o` files is taken as such, make thinks that you are really producing them in the local directory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically change:

```
%.o : $(SRC)/%.c
        @echo "----" $@ "----"
        $(COMPILER) -c $< -o $(OBJ)/$@
```

To:

```
$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
        $(COMPILER) $< -o $@
```